# How to box every char of a long string within a visual grid

Tags: longtable, loops, ltxtable, tcbinputlisting

a newbie here ;)

I'm trying to create a box around every character of a super long string  (eg. let's say something like all the unicode chars) loaded from an external file (`inputlisting` probably?).

I need the boxes to be `1em ✕ 1em` to be visually appealing, or any fixed defined size.

I don't know the number of columns that fit into the `linewidth` and I expect to find a solution that handles `breaklines` and on multiple pages.

The result should be something like this:

[image: Example]

In your opinion is `tabular` the way to go (eg. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457113/loop-generated-latex-table-using-tokens)) or something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359189/looping-over-strings#_=_) to loop over strings?

I feel like `ltxtable` and other stuff I found reading here and there are the way to go, but there are really dozens packages to handle tables, and I'm not able to find where to start from.

**PS.** No problem on go with solutions like `luatex` and similar as long as it works ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple loop with `\framebox`es should do.  Run with LuaLaTeX (XeLaTeX should also work).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcount\curchar
\noindent
\loop\ifnum\curchar<"10000
    \iffontchar\font\curchar
        \framebox[5ex]{%
            \vrule height 2.5ex depth 1.5ex width 0pt\relax
            \Uchar\curchar
        }\hskip0pt
    \fi
    \advance\curchar by 1
\repeat

\end{document}
```

First page of output:

[image]

Comment: Super, thanks, I'm trying to understand your commands. I was able to reproduce it locally. So it's a loop over the variable `curchar` that holds the current character that is a number (the first 10000) and is then printed with the `\Uchar` command, right? Then how to pass an argument of my `own string` to loop those characters? Another thing I'm also trying to remove the margin... without success :( following this options http://joshua.smcvt.edu/latex2e/_005cfbox-_0026-_005cframebox.html

Comment: @pna You haven't posted a minimal working example, so this is where it ends.

Comment: Thanks for your help, then.